# NFT transfer to a contract in ERC1155 standard

Tags: contract-development, ethers.js, hardhat, nft, erc-1155

NFTS transfer from minter to contract isn't working, below is the detailed problem.

NFT.sol

```
// SPDX-License-Identifier: UNLICENSED
pragma solidity ^0.8.19;

import {ERC1155} from "@openzeppelin/contracts/token/ERC1155/ERC1155.sol";

contract NFT is ERC1155{

string public name;
string public symbol;
string public baseURI;

// This will also work

// uint256[] public ids = new uint256[](10);
// uint256[] public values = new uint256[](10);

uint256[] public ids;
uint256[] public values;

uint256 public totalCount;
uint256 public batchCount;

constructor(string memory _name, string memory _symbol, string memory _baseURI) ERC1155(_baseURI){
    name = _name;
    symbol = _symbol;
    baseURI = _baseURI;
}

function mintTokens() public{

    totalCount = totalCount + 10;
    batchCount++;

    for(uint i = totalCount-9; i<=totalCount; i++){

        // This will also work
        
        // ids[i - (totalCount - 9)] = i;
        // values[i - (totalCount - 9)] = 1;

        ids.push(i);
        values.push(1);
    }

    _mintBatch(msg.sender, ids, values, "");
}


function totalSupply() public view returns (uint256){
    return totalCount;
}

    
}
```

MarketPlace.sol

```
// SPDX-License-Identifier: UNLICENSED
pragma solidity ^0.8.19;

import "@openzeppelin/contracts/token/ERC1155/IERC1155.sol";

import "hardhat/console.sol";

contract MarketPlace {

    uint public batchListedCount;
    uint public batchIdIndex;

    uint[] public batchItemsIds = new uint256[](10);
    uint[] public batchItemsValues = new uint256[](10);

    mapping(uint => bool) public itemSold;

    struct Batch {
        uint batchId;
        uint[] batchItemsIds;
        uint[] batchItemsValues;
        IERC1155 nft;
        uint batchPrice;
        address payable seller;
    }

    event Offered(
        uint batchId,
        address indexed nft,
        uint batchListedCount,
        uint batchPrice,
        address indexed seller
    );

    event Bought(
        uint batchId,
        uint batchItemIds,
        address indexed nft,
        uint batchListedCount,
        uint batchPrice,
        address indexed seller,
        address indexed buyer
    );

    mapping(uint => Batch) public batchs;

    function makeBatch(IERC1155 _nft, uint _batchId, uint _batchprice) external {

        batchListedCount++;

        for (uint i = 0; i < 10; i++) {
            batchItemsIds[i] = _batchId * 10 - (10 - (i + 1));
            batchItemsValues[i] = 1;
        }

        _nft.safeBatchTransferFrom(msg.sender, address(this), batchItemsIds, batchItemsValues, "");

        Batch storage newBatch = batchs[batchListedCount];
        newBatch.batchId = batchListedCount;
        newBatch.batchItemsIds = batchItemsIds;
        newBatch.batchItemsValues = batchItemsValues;
        newBatch.nft = _nft;
        newBatch.batchPrice = _batchprice;
        newBatch.seller = payable(msg.sender);

        emit Offered(
            _batchId,
            address(_nft),
            batchListedCount,
            _batchprice,
            msg.sender
        );
    }

    function purchaseOneItemFromBatch(uint _batchId) external payable {

        if (batchIdIndex < 10) {
            batchIdIndex++;
        } else {
            if (batchIdIndex >= 10) {
                batchIdIndex = 0;
            }
            batchIdIndex++;
        }

        Batch storage batch = batchs[_batchId];
        require(_batchId > 0 && _batchId <= batchListedCount, "Item doesn't exist");

        batch.seller.transfer(batch.batchPrice / 10);

        batch.nft.safeTransferFrom(address(this), msg.sender, batch.batchItemsIds[batchIdIndex - 1], batch.batchItemsValues[batchIdIndex - 1], "");
        emit Bought(
            _batchId,
            batch.batchItemsIds[batchIdIndex - 1],
            address(batch.nft),
            batchListedCount,
            batch.batchPrice,
            msg.sender,
            batch.seller
        );
    }
}
```

the describe portion of test file -

```
describe("Marketplace", ()=>{

let deployer, market, nft, baseUri='Sample URI', addrs

beforeEach(async()=>{      
    const MARKET = await ethers.getContractFactory("MarketPlace")
    const NFT = await ethers.getContractFactory("NFT")

    addrs = await ethers.getSigners();
    deployer = addrs[0];

    market = await MARKET.deploy()
    await market.waitForDeployment()
    nft = await NFT.deploy('Xbit','XB',baseUri)
    await nft.waitForDeployment()
})
    



describe('Making market place item', ()=>{

    let batchPrice =2;
    let result;

    

    beforeEach(async()=>{
        console.log('market address', await market.getAddress())

        await nft.connect(addrs[1]).mintTokens()

        await nft.connect(addrs[1]).setApprovalForAll(await market.getAddress(), true)

    })
    it('should track item created in marketplace, tranfer NFT to marketplace from seller, and omit Offered event', async()=>{

        await expect((await market.connect(addrs[1]).makeBatch(await nft.getAddress(), 1 , toWei(batchPrice))).wait())
        .to.emit(market, "Offered")
        .withArgs(
          1,
          await nft.getAddress(),
          1,
          toWei(batchPrice),
          addrs[1],
        )
        
        });

}))
```

Error :-

```
1) Marketplace
   Making market place item
     should track item created in marketplace, tranfer NFT to marketplace from seller, and omit Offered event:
 Error: VM Exception while processing transaction: reverted with custom error 'ERC1155InvalidReceiver("0xDc64a140Aa3E981100a9becA4E685f962f0cF6C9")'
at NFT._doSafeBatchTransferAcceptanceCheck (@openzeppelin/contracts/token/ERC1155/ERC1155.sol:432)
at NFT._updateWithAcceptanceCheck (@openzeppelin/contracts/token/ERC1155/ERC1155.sol:208)
at NFT._safeBatchTransferFrom (@openzeppelin/contracts/token/ERC1155/ERC1155.sol:260)
at NFT.safeBatchTransferFrom (@openzeppelin/contracts/token/ERC1155/ERC1155.sol:131)
at MarketPlace.makeBatch (contracts/MarketPlace.sol:58)
at processTicksAndRejections (node:internal/process/task_queues:95:5)
at HardhatNode._mineBlockWithPendingTxs (node_modules\hardhat\src\internal\hardhat-network\provider\node.ts:1866:23)
at HardhatNode.mineBlock (node_modules\hardhat\src\internal\hardhat-network\provider\node.ts:524:16)
at EthModule._sendTransactionAndReturnHash (node_modules\hardhat\src\internal\hardhat-network\provider\modules\eth.ts:1482:18)
at HardhatNetworkProvider.request (node_modules\hardhat\src\internal\hardhat-network\provider\provider.ts:124:18)
at HardhatEthersSigner.sendTransaction (node_modules\@nomicfoundation\hardhat-ethers\src\signers.ts:125:18)
at send (node_modules\ethers\src.ts\contract\contract.ts:313:20)
```

**In SUMMARY**

When `makeBatch` function in **Marketplace.sol** is triggered, it's showing the error that i mentioned above. it looks like when `_nft.safeBatchTransferFrom(msg.sender, address(this), batchItemsIds, batchItemsValues, "");` is called transfer of NFTs from minter to **Marketplace.sol** isn't working, but i don't know the reason.

Any help appreciated, Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

As your marketplace is a contract, the ERC1155 token contract will require it to be a receiver contract to avoid any locking of tokens.
The marketplace contract needs to be receiver-compatible by inheriting the ERC1155TokenReceiver interface. More details [here](https://eips.ethereum.org/EIPS/eip-1155#erc-1155-token-receiver)

You can also check openzeppelin's receiver contract [here](https://github.com/OpenZeppelin/openzeppelin-contracts/blob/master/contracts/token/ERC1155/IERC1155Receiver.sol)

Comment: I tried IERC1155Receiver, and implemented it's onERC1155BatchReceived function, but on doing so it's showing compilation error as declare Marketplace as abstract and some other issues, so I tried inheriting from ERC1155Holder and thankfully it's worked! But i don't know why it's not working with IERC1155Receiver.